# I am trying to figure out a google sheet formula that will add 3.13 to a cell for every 12.50 in the total amount cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In google sheets I have tab that has a dollar amount. In the next cell I need it to calculate that for every $12.50 from the left cell equals/adds 3.13 in the cell on the right. Can anyone help with this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's math. Divide by 12.5 and multiply by 3.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,QUOTIENT(A2:A,12.5)*3.13))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below and let us know your feedback.

```
=A1+ INT(A1/12.5)*3.13
```

[image]